# How to create an illusion of movement in space?

Tags: game-design

I am currently making a space game. The player's ship is stationary at world origin while things come towards it. However, the player is supposed to move towards the next destination.

To create the illusion of movement, I have particles moving backwards while my ship remains stationary. However, the particles seems to get lost visually during complex battle scenes.

Is there any other way to give the illusion of movement where there is an absence of stationary reference points?

Here are some screenshots of the game

[image]
[image]

---

The referenced question that has been identified as a duplicate does not answer my question. It is somewhat unclear what some of the implementations are. I seek a tried example that is used in other games if possible.

Most of the implementations suggested is more relevant to a first person perspective. I am looking for 3rd person effect where the player cannot "Visually Feel" the effect through a jolt.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your game?  Is it 2d?  3d?  Is it top-down? Side view?  What do you mean by the particles get lost?

Comment: Either create a parallax background or play with the FOV to simulate how space begins to get distorted at high speeds

Comment: I see missiles emitting smoke particles. Would it be an idea to have the smoke have an extra horizontal travel motion? So a smoke particle quickly moves to the left of the screen once it is emitted? Same goes for debris flying of the spaceships.